# How to queue API requests with PHP in WordPress?

Tags: api, server, docker, internal-server-error

I'm developing a plugin to manage some simple custom APIs.
I'd like to handle clients requests to APIs with a queue, so as not to handle all requests in parallel but one at a time, with a FIFO logic: when one request has been satisfied, the next one in the queue is processed and so on ...

I tried to use the [Pheanstalk](https://packagist.org/packages/pda/pheanstalk) library but the server responds with error 500, as a development environment I am using [Devilbox](http://devilbox.org/), how should I configure the container to be able to use this library correctly? And what requirements should the server have in production?

Any different solution to manage APIs requests via a queue?

Comment: a 500 error is just a super generic something broke or returned an error status code, you need to look at your PHP error log to find the actual error message. As for Devilbox I don't think this is the place to ask for help configuring devil box to use a general PHP library. Also Pheanstalk is just a client library that still requires you to install beanstalkd on the server

Comment: @TomJNowell ok, I know this is not the right place for Devilbox questions. Mainly, I'd like to know if there are suggestions about enqueue APIs requests...

Comment: Have you seen [wp-background-processing](https://github.com/deliciousbrains/wp-background-processing) library?